# pg_get_serial_sequence returns nothing (empty string)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have many tables with auto-inc PKs, and for most of them `pg_get_serial_sequence` returns (as I would expect) the sequence name behind the auto-inc i.e. SERIAL PK. But for one table `pg_get_serial_sequence` returns just an empty string?!

Now... I generated CREATE scripts for these tables but I don't see any principle difference between the create scripts of these tables (those for which `pg_get_serial_sequence` works OK, and the table for which it does not work OK i.e. for which it returns an empty string).

Both have SERIAL PK columns backed by some sequences. So the situation seems identical to me. Yet for one of my tables `pg_get_serial_sequence` does not return the name of that backing sequence, it just returns empty string.

What could this particular table be missing?

Do I need to make something special to set a given sequence as a SERIAL sequence?!

If not, what should I be looking for? What am I missing?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the actual code. Please [edit] your question and add the complete `CREATE` scripts for all tables involved and the code where you use `pg_get_serial_sequence()`

Comment: Maybe my issue is related to this:  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4800.1445898830%40sss.pgh.pa.us#4800.1445898830@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: So did you rename that sequence at some point?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I didn't touch it. I just inherited this stuff when I started looking at it. Problem fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This depends on how the table has been created. When you use `serial`, the sequence is created and associated with the table automatically:

```
create table my_table_auto(id serial);
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table_auto', 'id');

   pg_get_serial_sequence    
-----------------------------
 public.my_table_auto_id_seq
(1 row)
```

When you create a sequence manually, it is not associated with the table:

```
create sequence my_sequence;
create table my_table_manually(id int default nextval('my_sequence'));
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table_manually', 'id');

 pg_get_serial_sequence 
------------------------

(1 row)
```

You can alter a sequence to associate it with a table:

```
alter sequence my_sequence owned by my_table_manually.id;
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table_manually', 'id');

 pg_get_serial_sequence 
------------------------
 public.my_sequence
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out myself. I don't know how the table was created. I didn't do it myself. Other folks do it and sometimes they do sloppy stuff. I just figured out that I have to say: `ALTER SEQUENCE t_name_seq OWNED BY t_name.id `

Comment: Interesting enough, none of my tools (DBeaver, pgAdmin) showed me that this particular sequence was not owned by any table column, while the other sequences were owned. Strange why the CREATE scripts of sequences don't show this info (which column owns the seq).

Comment: Apparently they used the 2nd approach which you mentioned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't use PgAdmin4 but PgAdmin III shows the difference in `CREATE TABLE...` script, though actually there is no info in `CREATE SEQUENCE ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are this table of yours is created with a `like` clause, i.e., out of a table template.

I use table templates a lot, to factorize some common columns, and I have found that if you include the primary key into the template then only one sequence generator is used for all of the derived tables.

This has two drawbacks:

- maybe this is not the expected behaviour as you planned an individual sequence for each derived table.
- when you run `pg_get_serial_sequence()` with the name of the derived table you get a `null` result.

Here you have a complete example, where `table1` and `table2` are derived from a table template named `template_basic`, including a sequence on `id`, and `table3` is a normal table.

```sql
drop table if exists table3 cascade;
drop table if exists table2 cascade;
drop table if exists table1 cascade;
drop table if exists template_basic cascade;

-- The template table
create table template_basic (
  id          serial,
  title       varchar,
  created_dt  timestamp,
  
  primary key (id)
);

-- A table derived from template_basic
create table table1 (
  like template_basic including all,
  
  phone_number  varchar,
  city          varchar,
  country       varchar
);

-- Another table derived from template_basic
create table table2 (
  like template_basic including all,
  
  first_name  varchar,
  family_name varchar
);

-- A normal table, but with an equivalent structure to table1 and table2
create table table3 (
  id            serial,
  title         varchar,
  created_dt    timestamp,
  
  phone_number  varchar,
  city          varchar,
  country       varchar,
  
  primary key (id)
);

-- Populate

insert into table1 default values;
insert into table1 default values;
insert into table1 default values;

insert into table2 default values;
insert into table2 default values;
insert into table2 default values;

insert into table3 default values;
insert into table3 default values;
insert into table3 default values;
```

Now, if you inspect these three tables you will see how `table2.id` share the same sequence as `table1.id`. Also, `table3.id` has its own sequence.

```sql
select id from table1;

id|
--|
 1|
 2|
 3|
 
select id from table2;

id|
--|
 4|
 5|
 6|
 
select id from table3;

id|
--|
 1|
 2|
 3|
```

When you retrieve the name of the sequence of `table1.id` or `table2.id` you get a `null`, as describe before.

```sql
select  pg_get_serial_sequence ('table1', 'id'); 

pg_get_serial_sequence|
----------------------|
                      |
select  pg_get_serial_sequence ('table2', 'id');

pg_get_serial_sequence|
----------------------|

select  pg_get_serial_sequence ('table3', 'id');

pg_get_serial_sequence|
----------------------|
public.table3_id_seq  |
```

To get the sequence of those two tables you have to invoke the template table name.

```sql
select  pg_get_serial_sequence ('template_basic', 'id');
                      
pg_get_serial_sequence      |
----------------------------|
public.template_basic_id_seq|
```